# How can I stop puddles of water forming on the shelves of my new refrigerator?

Tags: refrigerator

How can I prevent puddles of water forming on the shelves of my new refrigerator.

Comment: Have you checked to see if drain system has frozen up (or not connected, properly or otherwise)? If it is, when it goes into a defrost cycle, water can leak into the frig instead of down the drain. Check your manual for directions on how to clear it.

Comment: Also check that all the door seals actually seal.

Comment: Are you putting hot items in before cooled? but Dorothy's answer seems the first step to take.

Comment: Do you put leaking packages in your fridge? If yes, stop doing that. If not, can you edit your question to clarify what you put in and how?

Comment: Defrosting in the fridge can also cause this (especially combined with other containers being open) the solution in that case is to stand the frozen container in a bowl to catch the water.

Comment: Where is the water?  My friend just moved into an apartment 2 weeks ago, and they were having many cups of water each day showing up on the shelves and in the crisper drawers ... as it was all coming down the back wall.  (so I suspected the freezer defrosting ... didn't know that there was a drain to check)

Answer (score 2):

Simply saying what MaxW said already: Make sure the fridge doors seal. When freezer doors don't seal you get that frost we all loved as kids but when the fridge door does not seal, you get little puddles forming around/under all your pots and containers. If this is the case, you can use the following suggestion from popularmechanics.com:

"This can be the result of a leaking door gasket. The gasket allows the cold air to constantly seep out, making the refrigerator run overtime and produce extra chill in the freezer. Check the gasket by placing a high-power flashlight or emergency battery-powered light unit in the freezer with the beam pointed at the door. Turn the light off in the kitchen and check around the perimeter of the door. If there is any light leakage, you'll need to replace the gasket, which can be purchased directly from the manufacturer or from large-appliance retailers."

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my question.  The problem was a leaking plastic Brita water pitcher.  Upon removing the pitcher from the refrigerator, the problem disappeared.  And to think that I bought a new refrigerator because of this problem!!

Thanks for all the good, logical answers.